# WordPress count post by meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

How can I count WordPress post?
I am using custom post type UI and advanced custom field. I have created a post type called **`product`** and it has a fieldname called **`product_family`** which is a select tag and it has a 3 option/value

1. Latest.
2. Car Navigation.
3. Car Recorder.

I tried codes like this but cannot get it. How can I count the number inside of the select tag.

Maybe I'm doing it all wrong. Please consider I'm a newbie. Any other way of making it display the count of the fieldname please share for learning.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'product_family'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$count = $query->post_count;
echo '<p>' . $count . '</p>';
```

this is my advanced custom field. i have post type name(product) and it has a fieldname(product_family) which is a select tag
[acf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mus4v.png)

i specify both value and label. this is what i want to be counted dynamically so that in the future if the client will add another value, the code will automatic count it.
[acff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et4RN.png)

Comment: What happens when you do this? Is the query working? What error do you receive? Why do you have `meta_key` in your args array?

Comment: i use the meta_key to point to the select tag. when i run this it show the number of all the products.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for this

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'product_family', //meta_key name
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'value' => ['Latest', 'Car Navigation', 'Car Recorder'] //list of values
        ]
    ],
];
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
echo $posts->post_count;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No value display mate. Regarding for the select tag(fieldname) i wanted it to be counted because it is for the client if he wants to add another option in the future.

Comment: Sorry I did't get you. You want to get the product count by `product_family`? right?

Comment: Yes. the product_family(fieldname) is a select tag which for now i put 3 options(Latest, Car Navigation and Car Recorder) but i wanted it to be dynamic. Thats why i need the product_family(fieldname) to be counted dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;

$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE ('post_type' = 'product' AND meta_key = 'product_family' AND meta_value = 'Latest' OR meta_value = 'Car Navigation' OR meta_value = 'Car Recorder' )");

/* Just add and combine AND / OR in your Query */

$qt = count($query);

echo $qt;
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
 $count = sizeof($query);
 echo '<p>' . $count . '</p>';
```

Comment: it display 1. but i have 3 inside the select tag.